# Symfony HttpClient, fail to authenticate external API witch Bearer

Tags: rest, symfony, oauth-2.0, request, http-headers

I have a problem, I try to use a external API, but the response of that APi is a 401.

1º- I send a request to get the auth token, works fine.

```php
$auth = $this->client->request(
    'POST',
    'https://api.namebright.com/auth/token',
    [
        'body' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $clientID,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        ],
    ]
);
```

2º- handler token, i dump the token is loocks fine

```php
$token = sprintf('Bearer %s', $auth->toArray()['access_token']);
```

3º- I make other request to get the API response, i got a 401.

```php
$response = $this->client->request(
    'GET',
    'http://api.namebright.com/rest/purchase/availability/google.pt',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => $token,
        ],
    ]
);
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. :(

I checked, for responses on the internet and i don't see the problem.
I Tried to change `Authorization` to `authorization`.
I tried to check the token in the postmen, works fine.

Comment: From https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#authentication it seems you should be able to pass `'auth_bearer' => $token` to options array. Or `'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token` should work too in the headers.

Comment: @Tomsgu, thanks for the help, i change from  `'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token` to `'auth_bearer' => $token` and its works, I don't why, is supposed to work with `'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $token` as well... Thanks so much, i spend so much time on this :(

Comment: Because it normally expects header to be in format: `Authorization: Bearer token-string`. The Bearer is what you were missing in your code. `auth_bearer` option just makes it simpler - adding the Bearer behind the scenes.

Comment: @Tomsgu I added the "Bearer" in `$token = sprintf('Bearer %s', $auth->toArray()['access_token']);` when I check the dump, the token is "Bearer {tokenKey}"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$response = $this->client->request(
'GET',
'http://api.namebright.com/rest/purchase/availability/google.pt',
[
    'auth_bearer' => $token,
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
]);
```